# Restore CountDownTimer object after rotation

Tags: android, bundle, parcelable, countdowntimer, onsaveinstancestate

When i rotate, onCreate method is called so i lose all of my vars , that's why i want to restore CountDownTimer object . The onTick and onFinish callback methods of CDT object are active as the countdownTimer keep running. I think the solution is to make parcable the object but i didn't manage to complete my code

I dont want to use Service coz the Android doc is spesific when to use Services and i think in my case i dont need a Service

```java
   //my try to make parsable the CDT object    
    public class MyCountDownTimer implements Parcelable {
            private CountDownTimer t;

            public  final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
                public MyCountDownTimer createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                    return new MyCountDownTimer(in);
                }

                public MyCountDownTimer[] newArray(int size) {
                    return new MyCountDownTimer[size];
                }
            };

            private MyCountDownTimer(Parcel in) {
                t = (CountDownTimer) in.readParcelable(Timer);
            }
            MyCountDownTimer(CountDownTimer t)
            {
                this.t =t;
            }

            @Override
            public int describeContents() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {

            }
        }


    //declaretion
    private CountDownTimer Timer;

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState){
         super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
         outState.putSerializable(COUNTDOWN,new MyCountDownTimer(Timer));
    }

    //on restore
    Timer = (CountDownTimer) savedInstanceState.getParcelable(COUNTDOWN);


    //when call Timer
     private void setTimer(long mTimeLeftInMillisfun){

            Timer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillisfun,1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {


                    textTimer.setText("Remain "+ l/1000+" Seconds");

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    //do sth
                }


            }.start();
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to save the `CountDownTimer` object or just the data within `CountDownTimer`? If just the data, you don't need to make your class implements `Parcelable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't parcel your timer. You will lose time on clock (may not be a lot but still) during parcel/unparcel process.

Use a ViewModel to survive your timer during configuration change (activity rotation).

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Sample code -

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private MutableLiveData<Long> timerLiveData;

public MyViewModel() {
    this.timerLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
}

public LiveData<Long> getTimerLiveData() {
    return timerLiveData;
}

public void requestTimer(long timeInMins) {
    if (countDownTimer != null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeInMins * 60 * 1000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timerLiveData.setValue(millisUntilFinished);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            timerLiveData.setValue(0L);
        }
    };
    countDownTimer.start();
}
```

}

Listen to timer from UI -

```
myViewModel.getTimerLiveData().observe(this, timeLeft -> Log.d("test", "timeLeft " + timeLeft);
```

Comment: Could you provide some code sir?? I have already a viewModel but i use to save data from db @Vishal Arora

Comment: `public void saveTimer (CountDownTimer t)
    {
        this.timer = t;
    }
    public CountDownTimer getTimer()
    {
        return timer;
    }`
I just create sth like this in my ViewModel

Comment: Yeah Sir, your solution is accepted. However i edit your solution a bit. What i mean?!?! In my View model i create 1 setter and 1getter mehod for the CountDownTimer. in this way when i create a CDT obj in my activity i store this object in view model by calling the setter method, and onInstanceState i call the getter method from ViewModel in order to retrieve it. It works too. Here Is the code sample

`private CountDownTimer timer
public void saveTimer (CountDownTimer t)
    {
        this.timer = t;
    }
    public CountDownTimer getTimer()
    {
        return timer;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

To restore your object on configuration change, you need to save it in the `savedInstanceState`:

```
 override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    outState.putParcelable("your_parcelable_object", myCountDownTimer)
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    myCountDownTimer = savedInstanceState?.getParcelable<MyCountDownTimer>("your_parcelable_object")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my problem is to make parcelable the countdownTimer object.

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition for `CountDownTimer.java`, it doesn't implement `Parcelable` interface:

```java
public abstract class CountDownTimer {

    /**
     * Millis since epoch when alarm should stop.
     */
    private final long mMillisInFuture;

    /**
     * The interval in millis that the user receives callbacks
     */
    private final long mCountdownInterval;

    private long mStopTimeInFuture;

    /**
    * boolean representing if the timer was cancelled
    */
    private boolean mCancelled = false;
    ...
```

And you are trying to make an un-parcelable object to be parcelable with code below:

```java
//my try to make parsable the CDT object    
    public class MyCountDownTimer implements Parcelable {
            private CountDownTimer t;
```

This is impossible (correct me if there is any way to do that), unless you save the data inside of CDT in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore it with the data you saved in `onCreate`.

Comment: Yeah that was my fault